# No resource identifier found for attribute 'autoSizeTextType' in package

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-support-library

I was trying to implement the Auto Resizing textviews added in Api level 26 with the release of Android O. But i get the above error while compiling. It seems like the autoSizeTextType parameter is not available. I use the below code.

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/autosizing-textview.html

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="net.ajith.androidlearning.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Android support repository: Rev 47

Answer (score 2):

Docs say:

> The Support Library 26.0 Beta provides full support to the autosizing
>   TextView feature on devices running Android versions prior to Android
>   O.

You need to upgrade your support lib to beta2.

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'

Don't forget to change your project `build.gradle` to:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve the dependency issue. But the Widget does not seem to change my text size dynamically as mentioned. Any idea? I am setting text from layout.

Comment: @AjithMemana I never used it myself but here is a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/9652/autosizing-textviews)

Answer (score 1):

```
  /**Try to use Beta2 Gradle dependency in build.gradle file **/


  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'

 // REQUIRED: Google's new Maven repo is required for the latest
 // support library that is compatible with Android O

 repositories
 {
   maven 
   {
       url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
   }
 }

 link ---> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

 https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve the dependency issue. But the Widget does not seem to change my text size dynamically as mentioned. Any idea? I am setting text from layout.